# VS Code - Debugger gives module error, but running same command from terminal works

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So I have this launch.json

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run main.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": ["-o", "storage/test",
                "-b", "projects/robustnav_baselines/experiments/robustnav_train", "objectnav_robothor_vanilla_rgb_augmenter_resnet_ddppo",
                "-trd", "dylan/subsample_task/1_percent/train"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Which essentially runs this command `python main.py -o storage/test -b projects/robustnav_baselines/experiments/robustnav_train objectnav_robothor_vanilla_rgb_augmenter_resnet_ddppo -trd dylan/subsample_task/1_percent/train`. When I run this command in the vs code terminal it runs fine, but when I use the debugger associated with the launch.json file. I get this exception:

**allenact/**init**.py**
[image]

Then as we can see `workspaceFolder` is at the root

[image]

So I'm not sure why it's not finding the `allenact` module even though you can clearly access it from the root as it is a folder accessible in the root with an `__init__.py` file.

Here is my terminal output when I run debugger. VS code will output commands in terminal when you run debugger:

```
cd /home/dyung6/robustnav ; /usr/bin/env /home/dyung6/anaconda3/envs/robustNav/bin/python /home/dyung6/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 33361 -- /home/dyung6/robustnav/main.py -o storage/test -b projects/robustnav_baselines/experiments/robustnav_train objectnav_robothor_vanilla_rgb_augmenter_resnet_ddppo -trd dylan/subsample_task/1_percent/train
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the "run and debug" tab from the sidebar and at the bottom you would find a section called "breakpoints".

Under that, **uncheck** "raised exceptions" and "user uncaught exceptions".

Comment: unfortunately it's still throwing the same exception

Comment: @Gooby please check updated answer

Comment: hmm okay so it got past the import error now it's complaining about `allenact` not having an attribute called `main`. This is so weird.

Comment: Could you update your question with the full error

Comment: nvm figured it out I accidentally changed the `main.py` file to try and fix the first problem which caused the new issue, but your answer solved the original problem

Comment: fixed my issue, thanks! I had turned on raised exceptions and then forgot to disable it.